# Why would my PHP code sometimes create multiple rows in my MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My MySQL db has 180k rows...7k of which are duplicates. Data is created via PHP (5.6.30) scripts run by a javascript web app doing POSTs.

That is, they have the same data and the same time stamp.

Here is the code that runs to create a row:

```
$log->lwrite('Do NOT have extCommentID / author: ' . $authorID);
             $query = "INSERT INTO anno_feedback (anno_fb_author_id, anno_fb_recip_ext_id, anno_fb_recip_ext_name, anno_fb_recip_avatar_url, anno_fb_ext_id, anno_fb_ext_sys_id, anno_fb_lib_id, anno_fb_group_id, anno_fb_comment_id, anno_fb_app_source, anno_fb_platform, anno_fb_use_custom, anno_fb_comment_text, anno_fb_url_target, anno_fb_word_target) VALUES ($authorID, '". $recipientID ."', '" .$recipientName . "', '" .$recipientAvatarURL . "', '" . $extCommentID . "', $sysID, $libID, $groupID, $commentID, '" . $appSource . "', '" . $platform . "',$commentUseCustom,'" . $commentText . "','" . $urlTarget ."','" . $wordTarget ."')";
             // $newFbID = mysqli_insert_id($connection);           //  Get ID of newly created row...
        //  //  echo "\n\nRunning query to create Group - $query";
         // $log->lwrite('New commentID created: ' . $newFbID);
    }       //  END else for no existing feedback

    //  NOW, regardless, run query...
    if(mysqli_query($connection, $query)){
        $newFbID = mysqli_insert_id($connection);           //  Get ID of newly created row...
        $log->lwrite('New commentID created: ' . $newFbID);
        echo "\n\nCreated/updated feedback row...for row: " . $newFbID;
    }   else {
        echo "ERROR: Was not able to execute $query. " . mysqli_error($connection);
    }
```

And a log example:

> [16/Oct/2018:07:13:27] (saveFeedback) -------------Starting save feedback for user / commentID: 5222 / 23093
>   [16/Oct/2018:07:13:27] (saveFeedback) Do NOT have extCommentID / author: 5222
>   [16/Oct/2018:07:13:27] (saveFeedback) New commentID created: 177444
>   [16/Oct/2018:07:13:27] (saveFeedback) -------------Starting save feedback for user / commentID: 5222 / 23093
>   [16/Oct/2018:07:13:27] (saveFeedback) Do NOT have extCommentID / author: 5222
>   [16/Oct/2018:07:13:27] (saveFeedback) New commentID created: 177445

These rows (177444 and 177445) are duplicates.

I don't believe I have issues in the web app that runs the PHP through a POST command (not duplicate listeners or form submissions). I think the PHP is running twice sometimes - maybe concurrency or server load issues?

What strategies can a PHP/MySQL solution use to avoid this? I've read about INSERT IGNORE but I'd have to check against a text field AND a date field to know whether a duplicate was being created - which feels expensive.

Any direction appreciated - there's probably some best practice that I'm ignorant of to assure single rows are created. Happy to provide more detail.

Comment: The duplication is not in here. Either the code is inside a loop, you're calling mysqli_query twice, or the form is being submitted more than once. You'll have to show more code or do more debugging to figure out why.

Comment: You can make the fields a compound unique index, in the DB which will make it impossible to insert 2x, you can also create a hash of the data and then make that unique index and save it. It's better to have the DB know it's unique then to rely on code, because of concurrency issues just like you describe.

Comment: As per my assumptions your using an ajax to save in the page and on success its again calling the same function with the values that you passed earlier

Comment: When do you log? If you only log per request, then it must be a double submit from the client, and your script just running on the same input, normally. If duplicated are right after the original, then that is more evidence of double submit. If duplicates are not right after the original, then something else is going on.

Comment: Many thanks for the different perspectives...
The time stamps are always the same - if it were double-submit from my javascript wouldn't there be a delay? Like one Ajax fires and then the next...creating 2 separate threads that would run one after the other?

Comment: Yes, a small delay.  Depends on how fast the double click is, and then if you do a select to find out if the row exists, the DB can cache the query results long enough so that when the second thread checks it's not only wrong, but it returns faster then the first one did.  Then one inserts,and the other inserts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What strategies can a PHP/MySQL solution use to avoid this? I've read about INSERT IGNORE but I'd have to check against a text field AND a date field to know whether a duplicate was being created - which feels expensive

Make a unique index.  Normally you cannot make a Text field unique (if you mean the text type, not VarChar).  This is often the stumbling block that trips people up.  How can you have a unique index if you need to check if a Text field is unique..

One way is you can create a hash of the data and then make that unique, which is almost as good.  You just have to maintain the hash. For example if they edit the post you'll have to update the hash, but it's really no big deal.

For example:

```
        $hash = hash('sha1', $date.$text);
```

Then create a new field in the db that is a unique index `CHAR(40)` with a `UTF8_bin` collation.  SHA1 is 40 bytes long, then the `UTF8_bin` is a binary format, that makes searching case sensitive.  Hashes are case sensitive.

In effect this takes your big blob of text (and the date) and compresses it into a 40 character hash you can index uniquely. Then it will be impossible to have duplicates.  SHA1 hashing is very fast, I once timed it and it was something like 30,000 hashes a second on my PC. I forget exactly though so I may be way off, but it was a lot, way more then I needed to worry about when I timed it.

`INSERT IGNORE` this is often misunderstood, all it does is ignore errors.  If you don't have a proper unique index, then you won't get an error for a duplicate and it won't help you at all. It's no slower then a normal insert, but It can suppress errors other then just the unique index fail.

One other thing, is you will have to remove the duplicates before you can fix the table.  You will also have to go back and create hashes for those records already saved. This shouldn't be too difficult, just make sure to back the table up before making any changes.

> I don't believe I have issues in the web app that runs the PHP through a POST command (not duplicate listeners or form submissions). I think the PHP is running twice sometimes - maybe concurrency or server load issues?

It could be as simple as someone double clicking the submit button.  I once had an office worker that had a bad mouse and every time she clicked a submit button it would double click it.  Because of concurrency you can't rely on code checks alone to keep it unique.

With a unique field in the DB, you can use `INSRT IGNORE`, `INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` or `REPLACE INTO`, all of which avoid the actual error making it to the application, and don't insert duplicates.  All have their own little querks though.  For example `INSERT ON DUPLICATE` will increase the Auto increment ID counter(not the row's id) even on updates, not a big deal but nice to know.  Replace deletes the current row and inserts a new one, so the Auto increment ID will change if not included in the query.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer...

Turns out the bulk of the duplicates were coming from double-clicks. Didn't even occur to me...but there are a number of ways users can add data: buttons, dropdowns, search (jQuery UI), context menus.

Only the buttons are creating duplicates. Context menu closes after you make a selection.

So I'll explore the hash as a way to solve...also might disable the buttons in question for a second after a click as a quick workaround...

Comment: I use a UI blocker, basically a dark (semi-transparent) overlay with a spinning GIF in the middle, that blocks the whole page, and when I do the AJAX call I display it and then in `.always()` I hide it.  It's pretty easy to make, and duplicate prevention on the DB, the overlay is mainly for the benefit of the end user, so they can see that its being saved (get instant feedback).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, and log report it looks like the data has submitted twice to the database.

In order to overcome this, please check the same date exists in the database table before insert the data. then you will not not have this issue.

To do that, add a query to check data, before insert.

Comment: I think this would be a good idea. How can one check if the same data exists before adding to it?